# Parameter is not valid when getting image from stream

Tags: c#, stream

I have this code:

```
              MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(newbytes, 0,
            newbytes.Length);
              ms.Position = 0;      
        ms.Write(newbytes, 0, newbytes.Length);
              Image img = Image.FromStream(ms);
            img.Save(@"C:\Users\gsira\Pictures\Blue hills5.jpg");
```

I get this error at the Image.FromStream(ms) call:

System.ArgumentException: Parameter is not valid.
   at System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(Stream stream, Boolean useEmbeddedColorManagement, Boolean validateIma

How can I resolve this? A couple of links which solve this problem (one on an MSDN thread) are broken so I am lost.

Answer (score 1):

If you initialise a MemoryStream with a byte array (which is what I am assuming `newbytes` to be), you should not need to write to it.

The call to `Write(newbytes, 0, newbytes.Length)` in your sample is completely redundant.

```
var s = new MemoryStream(newbytes, 0, newbytes.Length);
var i = Image.FromStream(s);

i.Save(@"C:\Users\gsira\Pictures\Blue hills5.jpg");
```

The above works for me where `newbytes` is a byte array of the contents of an image file on my hard drive.

Answer (score -1):

Try to rewind memory stream to the very beginning after you wrote bytes into it.

```
ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
```

Than it's possible to create Image.FromStream

Comment: Same problem. Code is:

            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(newbytes, 0,
                newbytes.Length);
                  ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            ms.Write(newbytes, 0, newbytes.Length);
                  Image img = Image.FromStream(ms);

Comment: You should Seek after ms.Write

Comment: Still the same problem. I have taken that line of code and cut and pasted it after the write.

Comment: I insert an image's bytes into sql server, and then get them back (in a seperate method). newbytes is the bytes of the image retrieved.

Comment: I suppose the problem is somewhere in binary putting/getting. Try to save array of bytes to hdd if it's image already.