# Retrieving an image from SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

I wrote this code but faced an exception that said: `Parameter Not Valid.`

```
    string connstr = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\db.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True";

    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
    conn.ConnectionString = connstr;

    conn.Open();

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.Connection = conn;

    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM tbl";

    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
    da.SelectCommand = cmd;

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    da.Fill(dt);

    byte[] barrImg = (byte[])dt.Rows[1]["image"];

    MemoryStream mstream = new MemoryStream();

    mstream.Write(barrImg, 0, barrImg.Length);
    mstream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

    img.Image = Image.FromStream(mstream);
    mstream.Close();
```

The exception is:

> `Parameter is not valid.`

in the `Image.FromStream` line of code.

I checked the value that in datatable was assigned to the image field. It was `System.Byte[]`. I traced the code. Every thing seems to be correct. But it does not work.

I searched around this problem. Another site preferred to set `mstream.Position = 0`. But that does not work.

I stored my image by this code.If it maybe that I saved this wrong!

```
    string connstr = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\db.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True";

    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
    conn.ConnectionString = connstr;

    conn.Open();

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.Connection = conn;

    string sql = "INSERT INTO tbl (name, family, image) VALUES ('name', 'family', '{0}')";
    sql = string.Format(sql, Image.FromFile("test.jpg"));

    cmd.CommandText = sql;
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    conn.Close();
```

new code to save the image:

```
public byte[] ReadFile(string sPath)
{
    byte[] data = null;


    FileInfo fInfo = new FileInfo(sPath);
    long numBytes = fInfo.Length;

    FileStream fStream = new FileStream(sPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

    BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fStream);

    data = br.ReadBytes((int)numBytes);

    return data;
}
```

and :

```
private void cmdSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string connstr = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\db.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True";

      byte[] imageData = ReadFile("test.jpg");

      SqlConnection CN = new SqlConnection(connstr);

      string qry = "insert into tbl (name, family, image) VALUES ('name', 'family', '{0}')";
      qry = string.Format(qry, imageData);

      SqlCommand SqlCom = new SqlCommand(qry, CN);

      CN.Open();
      SqlCom.ExecuteNonQuery();
      CN.Close();
}
```

Comment: I changed this question slightly so that it reflects the actual error currently faced.  The previously named one was not germaine.

Comment: While we are at it, please post your exact error message.

Comment: An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Drawing.dll

Additional information: Parameter is not valid.

Answer (score 2):

Um, that's not going to work.

Your code that "stores" the image, well, doesn't really do what you think it does.

It is putting the **value** "test.jpg" into the image field.  That isn't the binary image data; only the *filename*.

So, when you go to pull it back out the `Image.FromStream(mstream)` call is going to blow chunks because the value "test.jpg" is not an image.. ergo: the *parameter is not valid*

Here is an example of what you need to be doing to actually put the image into the database:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/21208/Store-or-Save-images-in-SQL-Server

Comment: @Amin:  You did what?  You *should* have modified your image saving code.  If so, update your question with the new code.

Comment: I did this like below: code[sql = string.Format(sql, Image.FromFile("test.jpg"));]  see to the main code.

Comment: @Amin: Doing a String.Format while building your inline sql **will not** work.  Please read the linked article.  You have to pass the actual image data as a binary object to the database server.  The best way to do this is through a parameterized query (which you should be doing anyway).

Comment: I had read this article today morning and I had problem with this.

Comment: @Amin: Did you copy the code from the article *exactly*?  If so, restructure your save code above rerun it and post that error message.

Comment: I can not answer my post so I have to edit the main post.see my code in main post please.

Answer (score 1):

You close the stream then try to pull an image from the stream, hence the error "cannot access a closed stream."

Try swapping the order of your last two lines:

```
img.Image = Image.FromStream(mstream);
mstream.Close();
```

Comment: @JYelton: I assume you haven't read until "I cleared the line mstream.Close(); but faced to another Exceptioon that said: Parameter is not valid. in last line of code" below the code ;)

Comment: Thanks for mention.Take it easy!

Comment: @Tim Point taken, though that at least clears up one of the problems.

Comment: For the exception "Parameter is not valid..." that usually has to deal with the data not being of a correct image type or format. Look at these related questions: [629955](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/629955/parameter-not-valid-exception-loading-system-drawing-image), [3036560](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3036560/parameter-is-not-valid-when-getting-image-from-stream), [1614773](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1614773/image-fromstreampostedfile-inputstream-fails-parameter-is-not-valid-async)

Comment: I edited the post.now you can my saving way of image if it is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```
using (MemoryStream mstream = new MemoryStream((byte[])dt.Rows[1]["image"]))
{
    img.Image = Image.FromStream(mstream);
}
```

Would simplify things. I suspect your problem would be you need to call mStream.Flush() after write and before the seek.

To put an image in to a database, one way is.

```
string connstr = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\db.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True";

using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connstr))
{
  using (SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand(conn))
  {
    comm.CommandText = "INSERT INTO tbl (name, family, image) VALUES (@name,@family,@Content)";
    comm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("name",DbType.String,"Fred"));
    comm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("family",DbType.String,"Flintstone"));
    using(FileStream fs = new FileStream("FredWilmaBamBamAndDino.jpg",FileMode.Open,FileAccess.Read))
    {
      comm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("content",DbType.Image,fs));
    }
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
  }
}
```

Notice it puts the content of teh file in the database. Since in the case of a jpg that content is most definitely not a string, use a parameterised query. Which youi should be doing anyway, develop a good habit.
You also need to suss out using, your code was leaking resources all over the place.

Comment: Forget it. Ask another question. How do I store the image and not the name of the file it was in, in my database....

Comment: I tested this but faced the same Exception. what is happend?

Comment: No point in testing retrieving an image from a database when you've put a string in it is there! Would you like the code to do that, or do you want to keep on using your version which never will?

Comment: Interesting solution that. Never going to work mind. That will put the classname of the variable in the database as in System.Drawing.Image.